# Android native SDL glContext messed up picture

Tags: java, android, c++, opengl-es-2.0, sdl-2

I'm trying to setup SDL2 native application with use of custom glContext.
Java part: this has by default Absolute layout which is deprecated. And i wonder if i need to use some kind of SurfaceView:

```
mSurface = new SDLSurface(getApplication());    

mLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
mLayout.setLeft(0);
mLayout.setTop(0);
mLayout.addView(mSurface);

setContentView(mLayout);
```

Next, i'm creating opengl context in my native code:

```
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, "opengles2");
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_OPENGL_SHADERS, "1");
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_ES);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 2);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 0 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8 );

    m_glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(_window);
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(_window, m_glContext);
```

Window is created like this:

```
m_mainWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("clovo", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 2048, 1536,
            SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
```

I thought the case may be in size of window, but after creation the size is fits the screen. Also, this code works fine in iOS.
I can't find a solution for a problem. Can't even find a problem. I'm new to Android, so maybe there something about glContext what i should know?

[image: Samsung galaxy tab 7 glXontext]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.
It's occur when i'm using my own framebuffers and then setting it back to default.
In order to not set wrong buffer at my renderer initialization i'm storing default framebuffer

```
GLint default_buffer;
glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &default_buffer);
```

And then i can restore default buffer to draw to screen.